# Is this possible in react-table: Displaying colored circles according to numbers?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Hello I have no idea on how to get the result on the right side picture. Is this possible with react-table ?? If yes, how do I do?
I have grades for comments `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`, and instead of display numbers, I would like to fill in different colors (regarding the value) circles.

```
export default function MenuDisplay() {
  const { menuId } = useParams();
  const { match } = JsonData;

  const [hideSelected, setHideSelected] = useState(false);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState({});

 ... 
  const matchData = (
    match.find((el) => el._id_menu === menuId)?._ids ?? []
  ).filter(({ _id }) => {
    if (hideSelected) {
      return !selected[_id];
    }
    return true;
  });

  const getRowProps = (row) => {
    return {
      style: {
        backgroundColor: selected[row.values.id] ? "lightgrey" : "white"
      }
    };
  };

  const data = [
    
    {
      Header: "Comments",
      accessor: (row) => row.comments
    },
    {
      Header: "Dishes",
      accessor: (row) => row.dishes,
      id: "dishes",
      Cell: ({ value }) => value && Object.values(value[0]).join(", ")
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <Table
        data={matchData}
        columns={data}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can just build up a string of some unicode characters to show those circles based on the number of comments in your data. You can see this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/number-2-dots-react-table-5g3wbl?file=/src/MenuDisplay.jsx) for an example, it's not exactly styled as your desired outcome, but should give you an idea.

Comment: @tromgy hi, is there a way to have a **border circle**  and then the color inside the bullet ??

Comment: You can use bitmaps or SVGs instead of the colored `<span>`s as it was in my example.

Comment: Never do that. I didn't see docs in react on bitmaps??

Comment: You can also make circles from `<div>`s. Here's an updated [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/number-2-circles-react-table-forked-9sz0e0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a Counter component that takes the count value & generates $count number of divs over a flex container div .... the child div can be fine tuned in width, height and border radius to make it circle of desired size & the background color set appropriately.

I forked your sandbox and made a sample implementation for you [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-4-buttons-forked-iqp0q8)

Hope this helps.